# How do I add global Rails helpers like has_many and devise_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, inheritance, include

In Rails, I'd like to apply functionality to many models at the same time, having the ability to add it to other models in the future.

I'm looking for something like...

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  some_tag
end
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  some_tag
end
```

to give those and any other models with

```
some_tag
```

the functionality of

```
class Functionality

  has_many :other_things, polymorphic: true

  def does_something
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: Create a module with the method you want to add to your classes:

```
module FooFunction
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def does_something(options = {})
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Next step: Include that module into the class

```
# in config/initializers/foo_function.rb
class Object
  include FooFunction
end
```

Comment: That's actually a really cool solution. My current solution has been a module that utilizes ```ActiveSupport::Concern``` and a ```included do``` block. You're saying to essentially extend the classes at startup though?

Comment: My solutions does basically the same then `ActiveRecord::Concern`, with the difference that it is plain Ruby and even works without Rails.